# How to set intent type to select only png and pdf files in ionic 1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Custom File Chooser plugin to select files which works fine.I would like to get only png and pdf files when opening the file chooser.But when i set the type to give only png and pdf files in the plugin it doesn't works.

Plugin Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType(type);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File");
    cordova.startActivityForResult(this, chooser, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);

    PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
    pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
    callback = callbackContext;
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
```

Using the Plugin:

```
customFileChooser.open({"image/png, application/pdf"}, function (uri) {
    $log.log('success uri is', uri);
  }, function (error) {
    $log.log('error is', error);
  });
```

As well as i would like to know how to convert the selected file to base64

Plugin Link: [click to view the plugin](https://github.com/EnriqueGL/cordova-custom-filechooser)

Comment: this plugin just work fine on my side ! and why you need to covert things to base64! its like coding in 90s! you should use multiPart network request ! ! 

Can you please tell the error ! or logs you are getting!

Comment: @Rizwanatta are you able to select only png and pdf files or all types of files